# URL routing relative paths with webforms ASP.net 4 and IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am try to get routing configured on an asp.net 4.0 site running on an IIS6 server.
I am using MapPageRoute and it takes me to the correct page. Problems I have encountered so far:

1. Extensionless Url Routing

   Solved by installing QFE described here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313092619/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx)
2. Static content such as js, css and images not displaying

   Solved using Chris Cavanagh's baseUrl technique described here chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/aspnet-routing-just-enough-rope/
3. Relative urls and postback scenarios

   NOT SOLVED. For some reason, relative paths are not being interpreted correctly. For example. asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/tree.jpg" is rendering out as and img with src="". I have been able to force it to work by setting the ImageUrl to an absolute path but I can't do this for everything. It is also affecting postback scenarios. Button clicks are taking me from (eg) localhost/website/articles/the-article_description/ to localhost/website/the-article-description which does not exist.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

For situations like #3, I have been placing a function there that returns a string to be used as a prefix URL for the production site. So for this part where you have:

```
mageUrl="~/images/tree.jpg"
```

adjust it to this:

```
mageUrl="<%= [YourNameSpace].AppMethod.IsProd() %>/images/tree.jpg"
```

'AppMethod' is some static class and the IsProd() function returns the prefix necessary to specify the production path if the app is running in production. Otherwise the prefix "~" if the app is running in dev. You can determine if the app is running in production by reading the machine name.

Answer (score -1):

do you have the RouteExistingFiles property set to true?